# Changing the Image for a detail disclosure button (Xcode 4.2)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5

I have used the following suggested routine to change the detail disclosure button image in a table view cell (in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath)

```
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

    UIButton *myAccessoryButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    [myAccessoryButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [myAccessoryButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell setAccessoryView:myAccessoryButton];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

However, the event `tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` is now no longer called on clicking the button.

Has anyone any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 7):

I've +1'd Fry's answer, but just to pull the code in from the other site to make SO more complete: The answer is that you have to accessoryButtonTapped.... call will not be made automatically as it would for the built-in detail-disclosure, so you have to do it yourself with the target of the button.

Translating from the link code to your example above, add this line after setImage:

```
[myAccessoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then add this later on:

```
- (void)accessoryButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil) {
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}
```

(copied verbatim from [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/71147-change-disclosure-button.html))

Note that this assumes that the button is created in the UITableViewController (in my case I'm creating one in a custom cell so the references are slightly different)

Explanation: the accessoryButtonTapped is a custom target method for our custom button. When the button is pressed ("TouchUpInside") then we find the indexPath of the cell at the point in which the press occurred, and invoke the method that the table view would ordinarily invoke.

Comment: Great...a similar implementation is here: http://iosdevblog.com/2014/07/26/custom-image-for-the-detail-disclosure-button/